# Laravel Eloquent Where Condition Not Work

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Table "items" with total no of data row = 11094 and there are 3 types of "status" (pending, publish & reject)

On MySQL Query 
`SELECT * FROM items WHERE status = 'pending'`  returns *1* row
`SELECT * FROM items WHERE status = 'publish'` returns *11091* rows 
`SELECT * FROM items WHERE status = 'reject'` returns *2* rows

*NB: Sum of the individual query result is equal to total no of rows.*

But In Laravel (5.4) Controller

`$items = Items::where( 'status', '=', 'publish' )->paginate(40);` returns 11091 rows

`$items = Items::where( 'status', '=', 'reject' )->paginate(40);` returns 0 rows (Though 2 Data Available in Table)

`$items = Items::where( 'status', '=', 'pending' )->paginate(40);` returns 0 rows (Though 1 Data Available in Table)

I can’t figure out what’s is the problem actually. Please Help.

Comment: can you try `Items::where( 'status', '=', 'publish' )->count();`?

Comment: everything seems correct. please try `->get()` instead of `->paginate()` and share the result to get better help

Comment: an even better trick is to call dd(Items::where( 'status', '=', 'pending' )->toSql()); To see what sql your query will produce

Comment: Items::where( 'status', '=', 'publish' )->count() = 11091 rows
Items::where( 'status', '=', 'pending' )->count() = 0 rows 
Items::where( 'status', '=', ‘reject )->count() = 0 rows

Comment: Items::where( 'status', '=', 'publish' )->get() = 11091 rows
Items::where( 'status', '=', 'pending' )->get() = 0 rows 
Items::where( 'status', '=', ‘reject )->get() = 0 rows

Comment: "select * from `items` where `status` = ? and `items`.`deleted_at` is null and `status` = ?" NB: all `items`.`deleted_at` is null

Comment: Can you pls. Check that data is exist with that status and also make sure it's not deleted as you're using softdelete for this.

Comment: everything is ok but getting no data !!  Items::where( 'status', '=', 'publish' )->getBindings()   return  array:2 [▼
  0 => "publish"
  1 => "publish"
]

Comment: You need to use this withTrashed() method to get deleted item also.

Comment: Full query would be something like this App\Flight::withTrashed()
                ->where('account_id', 1)
                ->get();

Comment: i tried but its only work for status = 'publish' not for('pending' or 'reject')

Comment: can you try this; where( "status", "reject" )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is the following.

```
select * from items where status = ? and items.deleted_at is null and status = ?
```

There is two statuses in the where, since your code clearly only has one.

```
$items = Items::where( 'status', '=', 'publish' )->paginate(40);
```

I'm fairly certain that somewhere in your code, you have a global scope, that filters by the status is publish. Find these and figure out how to solved it from there.

If you do the following, i will highly like believe your logic would work.

```
$items = Items::withoutGlobalScopes()->where( 'status', '=', 'reject' )->paginate(40);

$items = Items::withoutGlobalScopes()->where( 'status', '=', 'pending' )->paginate(40);
```